# Android Studio + Java JDBC (no suitable Driver found and many other error displayed)

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio, localhost

While testing my login form With a local server currently using MAMP I always encounter the following error when I try to conduct log in test:

```
    W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jbdc:mysql://localhost/phpMyAdmin/diplomanya
    W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:605)
    W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
            at fr.ibra_yous.diplomany_v00001.ConnectBdd.ConnexionSQLBdd(ConnectBdd.java:20)
            at fr.ibra_yous.diplomany_v00001.Log_in.Connect(Log_in.java:57)
            at fr.ibra_yous.diplomany_v00001.Log_in.access$000(Log_in.java:15)
            at fr.ibra_yous.diplomany_v00001.Log_in$1.onClick(Log_in.java:34)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
            at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.ResultSet java.sql.Statement.executeQuery(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    W/System.err:     at fr.ibra_yous.diplomany_v00001.Log_in.Connect(Log_in.java:61)
            at fr.ibra_yous.diplomany_v00001.Log_in.access$000(Log_in.java:15)
            at fr.ibra_yous.diplomany_v00001.Log_in$1.onClick(Log_in.java:34)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
            at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I'm new to Android Studio and Java thus is why I don't have any clue about the meaning of them so I would like to request a little assistance so I can understand and not remake the mistake who lead me to these error please because I will have to make a register form.

I don't know if I should joint all the code concerned which are the log_inactivity which contain my log_in form, the manifest file which I added this line:

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
```

and here the class code which allow the connection to the dbb:

````
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    
    public class ConnectBdd {
    
        public static String Driverjbdc = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        public static String url = "jbdc:mysql://localhost/phpMyAdmin/diplomanya";
        public static String password = "root";
        public static String user = "root";
    
        public static Statement ConnexionSQLBdd() {
    
            try {
                Class.forName(Driverjbdc);
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                return stmt;
    
            } catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
    
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
    
        }
    }
    ``` 
    The log in code : 
    ``` 
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    
    public class Log_in extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private EditText inIdInput , inPasswordInput;
        private Button logButton , singInBtn;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    
            inIdInput = this.findViewById(R.id.id_champ);
            inPasswordInput = this.findViewById(R.id.id_pass_champ);
            logButton = this.findViewById(R.id.id_log_button);
            singInBtn = this.findViewById(R.id.id_singIn_button);
    
    
            logButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Connect();
                }
            });
    
            singInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent singInActivityIntent = new Intent(Log_in.this,
                            Sing_in.class );
                    startActivity(singInActivityIntent);
                }
            });
    
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9 ){
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
    
        }
    
        private void Connect() {
            try{
                ConnectBdd connBdd = new ConnectBdd();
                Statement stmt = connBdd.ConnexionSQLBdd();
    
                String Request = "SELECT password_user FROM users WHERE mail_user = "+inIdInput.getText().toString()+"";
    
                final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Request);
                if (rs.getString(1).equals(inPasswordInput.getText().toString())){
                    NextActivity();
                }
    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        private void NextActivity() {
            Intent redirect = new Intent(Log_in.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(redirect);
            finish();
        }
    }
    ``` 

I really need help. Thank you.
````

Comment: JDBC is not designed for use with mobile devices. Android does not have a MySQL JDBC driver. Also, your database is not running on `localhost`, as `localhost` is your phone. "I'm new to android studio and java" -- what Android app development book are you reading that is teaching you to use JDBC?

Comment: Thanks you for the awnser i was using a tutorial on YouTube about connecting to a remote database with JDBC what would you recommend me to do then ? is there another solution beside MYSQLI ?

Comment: "i was using a tutorial on YouTube about connecting to a remote database with JDBC" -- on Android? How bizarre. "what would you recommend me to do then ?" -- create a Web service. Have the Web service talk to the database. Have the app talk to the Web service.

Comment: Yes here the following tutorial : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkDq7r6OFWw) and it's not the only one i found about it . As for the web service How should i make it does it have to be witted with ASP.NET ? and also thank you for the suggestion i will come back if i have more question.

Comment: "does it have to be witted with ASP.NET" -- probably not, but I do not do much Windows development.

Comment: I see i will look about it . Thanks you very much for the suggestion and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the `SQLException` you get is that that JDBC is not developed and designed for the use with mobile devices. Unfortunately `Android` does not even have a `MYSQL JDBC driver`.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply i decided to use jdbc after finding that you can use it with java to connect to a remote database and i also saw that it work with mobile according to the video i saw on YouTube if it's not suppose to work what should i use to get the result i want please ?